# C# Assigning Enum value to object

Tags: c#, performance, object, enums, box

In some places of our code, we are assigning enum value to object variable (ex: object value = DayOfWeek.Sunday). I was thinking on the line that enum underlying type is int, so why not use (int) and then call .ToString() to avoid boxing. To my happiness, It seems to avoid boxing (I checked IL code) but to my surprise, that part of code took more time to execute and allocated more memory too. I used BenchmarkDotNet tool to test performance differences. Below are the code samples,

1) Returning enum value, boxing happens (IL code below)

```
public object AssingEnumToObject()
    {
        return DayOfWeek.Sunday;
    }

  // Code size       7 (0x7)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0001:  box        [mscorlib]System.DayOfWeek
  IL_0006:  ret
```

2) Using (int), still boxing happens understandably.

```
public object AssingEnumIntToObject()
        {
            return (int)DayOfWeek.Sunday;
        }

// Code size       7 (0x7)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0001:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_0006:  ret
```

3) Using (int) then ToString(). Now its string which is returned for method requiring object return type. No boxing in IL but call to Int32.ToString() method.

```
public object AssingEnumIntStringToObject()
        {
            return ((int)DayOfWeek.Sunday).ToString();            
        }

  // Code size       10 (0xa)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] int32 V_0)
  IL_0000:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0001:  stloc.0
  IL_0002:  ldloca.s   V_0
  IL_0004:  call       instance string [mscorlib]System.Int32::ToString()
  IL_0009:  ret
```

To my surprise, BenchmarkDotNet tool shows, method 3 (AssingEnumIntStringToObject) is taking longer and allocating more memory.

[Results of BenchmarkDotNet tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCVjm.png)
What am I missing here? Is it because of this rule in CSharp Language Specification "From any enum-type to the type System.Enum" ? If so, how this works?

Please explain me. Thanks.

Edit:

Thanks @JonSkeet and @Craig for the answers. I failed to take into account the cost of creating string reference. I understood now.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Assigning an enum value to an `object` variable is *completely* different to assigning a string value. And why cast if you then want to get a string representation? There's no point in anyone trying to help you optimize if it's unclear what result you want - you've given three completely different results here.

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet 

Actually, I was assigning enum value to sqlparameter class whose value parameter is of type object. 

public SqlParameter(string parameterName, object value)

ex: new SqlParameter("@Day", DayOfWeek.Sunday)

I was thinking converting to string representation will avoid unnecessary boxing. So, I just gave a try to check how it behaves and works.

If possible, could you also explain why its three completely different results? 

I am asking in stackoverflow first time. Sorry If i am not asking in right way.

Comment: If you're creating a `SqlParameter`, presumably you're going to send that to SQL. The cost of boxing will be **utterly irrelevant** compared with that cost. (And as for why they're different: one will be a boxed enum value, one will be a boxed int, one will be a string reference. Those are different types...)

Comment: "String reference" - yes, missed to consider this completely. Thank you very much for really quick response. 

On a side note: I read your blog regularly (though I never commented, Sorry for that. I am still in learning phase) . Its great. Thanks one more time for writing :)

Answer (score 1):

Method 3 is taking longer because it is adding a function call to ToString and allocating and assigning a string, all of which takes extra time.

Method 3 is taking more memory because it is allocating a string.  Like with the boxing conversions, this is adding a reference (pointer-sized), but it is also adding the string itself.  The string will be at least the size of an int: at minimum, it has a counter for the size (four bytes, I believe) plus the buffer for the characters (minimum one character for your case).  Thus, this is taking more than double the additional memory vs the other two, which at most only add a reference (pointer-sized).

Comment: Hi @Craig Thank you. Jon Skeet gave me good heads up and you gave me detailed one. 

So, letting int type to box is far better than doing ToString()? say in string.concat() (or '+' operator) usage.

Comment: If you are putting it into a string, then a string conversion is going to happen at some point anyway.  I would recommend against profiling this particular piece of the operation in isolation.  If this is truly a significant bottleneck, then profile the entire operation (including the concat or operator+); don't just compare this piece of it.  The boxed versions will incur overhead to do a string conversion elsewhere, and these sorts of performance details tend to be difficult to impossible to figure out just from inspection.